# How to check if objects position is greater than an array of objects AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop, position, flashdevelop

Hey everyone so I'm trying to figure out how to check if one movie Clips x position which is called `ball` is greater than an array of objects x position which is called `car`. So I have an array setup with the `car` the car's main timeline consist of 4 frames that holds the same movie Clip just different sizes on each frame to make the game harder.

So what I want to do is check whenever the `ball` has jumped over the current `car` then add plus one to the score. But I am having trouble trying to figure this out. Here is what I have so far:

In my Enter Frame Game Loop I have the Function `checkAddPoints`:

```
private function gameLoop(e:Event):void 
    {
        checkBunnyHitObstacles();
        checkAddPoints();
    }
```

Then The function:

```
private function checkAddPoints():void 
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < aCarArray.length; i++)
        {
            var currentCar:car = aCarArray[i];

            if (ball.x > currentCar.x)
            {
                nScore ++;
                updateCurrentScore();

            }
        }

    }
```

So I am getting the current `car` in the loop and trying to check if the `ball` has jumped over it. I thought the most logical thing to do was to check if the `ball` x position was greater than the `car` x position then it would work. But it just adds a endless amount of numbers and not just one like I want.

Does anyone know what i need to do?

UPDATE: This seems to work haven't had any errors yet

```
if (currentcar.x - 15 < ball.x && currentCar.x + 15 > ball.x)
            {
                trace("AddPoint Success");
                nScore++;
                updateCurrentScore();

            }
```

Comment: So you have several cars on the scene? Do you want award player for every car and only one time score award?

Comment: Yes the Cars are added to the screen by a timer then once they leave the screen they get destroyed. If the ball jumps over the car then add one point. Basically just add one point for every car the ball jumps over without hitting the car. I already created the function to check the hittest for the array of cars which works fine. But just getting to add one point for every time the ball has jumped over the car is kinda hard

Answer (score 1):

Storing flag aboud award status in the car should help in your task. If you add flag to the car, let's say `car.isAwarded`, by default `isAwarded` is `false`, you will be able award only once for every car:

```
private function checkAddPoints():void {
    var i:uint, len:uint = aCarArray.length, currentCar:car;
    for (i; i < len; ++i) {
        currentCar = aCarArray[i];

        //Award only once
        if (!currentCar.isAwarded && ball.x > currentCar.x) {
            nScore++;
            currentCar.isAwarded = true;
            updateCurrentScore();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so i would still keep the var currentCar:car = aCarArray[i]; in the function?

Comment: Thanks but i seem to get this error on the where you add the var i:.....currentCar:car i get this: Access of possibly undefined property isAwarded through a reference with static type car.

Comment: Of course, because It's only idea, how you could resolve your problem. It's up to you, to add isAwarded property to the `car` class.

Comment: oh I didnt know i had to add isAwarded to my car class thought i could do it all in the main engine class. Still new to a lot of this.

Comment: so does the isAward boolean have to be in the car class or can it be in the main Engine class? I'm having trouble trying to figure this out